# How to divide the x-axis in two parts in highcharts?

Tags: html, highcharts

i want to plot monthly data for two years in single chart.
So i want to divide my x-axis into two for both years.

How can i achieve this?
This is the sample data and sample chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWeR3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDBZg.png)

Comment: Could you share an example of your data? Also, an image of the wanted result could be very useful.

Comment: Hey i have added sample data and sample chart in the description. Can you please suggest which functionality can be use to split the x-axis like this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the images. You can achieve the wanted effect by using the `grouped categories` custom plugin.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c48ysdnj/

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [{
      name: "2019",
      categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    }, {
      name: "2020",
      categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    }]
  },
```

API: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It is working with the sample data but not in my production environment. I am getting [object Object] instead of x-axis categories.

Comment: @VM007, could you share an sample of your data?